# Add extra (dropdown) field to gdm3 greeter

Tags: gdm3

I'm really going far outside my comfortzone here, but I was wondering: can I add a third (dropdown) field to the gdm3-(GTK)-greeter and then capture the input that it sends (probably to the Gnome session)?

Usecase: I have several hotseats in my office, with a VoIP-telephone next to it. I have configured a click-to-dial add-on in firefox (telify), but of course, when you're not at your 'regular' desk, then this is worthless. Thus I would like to add a dropdown select, giving the users the possibility to select which telephone is on their desk.

Is this possible? Thx for any pointers!

Comment: If you're talking about the sessions list that's available via dropdown menu at gdm login screen then you could certainly add another entry. The session files are similar to _.desktop_ launchers and are located in `/usr/share/xsessions`. Have a look at those files and see if you can come up with something that suits your needs (I don't quite understand the meaning of "select which telephone is on their desk").

Comment: Well, if user A sits at desk 1 with pc1 and tel1, then I would like to present that user with the choice to select telephone 1b. I have however solved the issue in another way, i.e. by using a settings file for Iceweasel that is positioned in /etc/iceweasel/prefs.js instead of in the user's profile - whereas a user can switch desks, the pc's and tel's will never change locations.